# Cannot Update Data on Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, insert-update, pfquery

Hi i am having a problem with updating my data on parse..

I have this code below..

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"RemittanceTable"];
[query whereKey:@"beneCode" equalTo:@"66gtbT"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        // NSLog(@"BENE DETAILS: %d", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);

            object[@"payoutRefNo"] = refNo;
            [object saveInBackground];
        }
    }else{
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }}];
```

And what i am trying to do is like this.. (in sql statement)

> UPDATE RemittanceTable SET payoutRefNo = 'RM4323' WHERE objectId = '66gtbT'

i am receiving an error states that..

> RIB[878:4d03] Error: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.18)

Please help me on this. if been looking over the internet and most of them tells that i should have acl on data browser table.. and i have a value of ACL field..

> {"*":{"read":true},"pXE8AuiGdA":{"write":true,"read":true}}

Using NSLOG.. here is the output..

```
RIB[954:60b] <RemittanceTable:Ncw9M79YbG:(null)> {
ACL = "<PFACL: 0x17df68a0>";
beneCode = 66gtbT;
beneMessage1 = "Allowance.";
beneMessage2 = "";
beneMobileNo = 09328694928;
beneName = "Lorraine Gomez";
payoutAccount = "";
payoutAddress = "";
payoutBank = "";
payoutMode = "";
payoutRefNo = "";
payoutZipCode = "";
remittanceAmount = "3000.00";
remitterAddress = "Camarin, Caloocan City";
remitterEmail = "ida.mayer@gmail.com";
remitterGender = Female;
remitterMobileNo = 09328694928;
remitterName = "Ida Mayer";
remitterRefNo = SMXGXc;
sourceAccount = "0009891123 - JOSE SANTOS";
status = 0;
```

}

Comment: your table name is correct?and there is a row containing 66gtbT in beneCode column?

Comment: yes, i just copy pasted it from the database

Comment: when i debugged it, it enters inside the for loop, which means there is a data like that...

Comment: See if this makes any difference: Although this query should return only 1 object, try updating the object(s) in the for loop, and move the save statement to after the for loop. You can then call [PFObject saveAllInBackground:objects];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ACL code to create ACL value on parse. This will restrict to edit Data from Android to iOs or vice versa..